# You tube videos asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, youtube

I am kind of stuck while displaying the similar videos list from youtube in aspx page. I could able to play a required videos, I also wanted the similar videos to be shown on screen.

Can you please help me out in getting the same using aspx.

Comment: have you seen the documentation for the youtube apis? They also have [examples in .net]( https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos] . There is a section on related videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api)?

> The Data API allows a program to perform many of the operations
>   available on the YouTube website. It is possible to search for videos,
>   retrieve standard feeds, and **see related content**. A program can also
>   authenticate as a user to upload videos, modify user playlists, and
>   more.

You can find example code in the [.NET Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet).